# File API seems to always write corrupt files when used in a loop, except for the last file

Tags: c#, file, stream, byte

I know the title is long, but it describes the problem exactly. I didn't know how else to explain it because this is totally out there.

I have a utility written in C# targeting .NET Core 2.1 that downloads and decrypts (AES encryption) files originally uploaded by our clients from our encrypted store, so they can be reprocessed through some of our services in the case that they fail. This utility is run via CLI using database IDs for the files as arguments, for example `download.bat 101 102 103` would download 3 files with the corresponding IDs. I'm receiving byte data through a message queue (really not much more than a TCP socket) which describes a .TIF image.

I have a good reason to believe that the byte data is not ever corrupted on the server. That reason is when I run the utility with only one ID parameter, such as `download.bat 101`, then it works just fine. Furthermore, when I run it with multiple IDs, the last file that is downloaded by the utility is always intact, but the rest are always corrupted.

This odd behavior has persisted across two different implementations for writing the byte data to a file. Those implementations are below.

`File.ReadAllBytes` implementation:

```
private static void WriteMessageContents(FileServiceResponseEnvelope envelope, string destination, byte[] encryptionKey, byte[] macInitialVector)
        {
            using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(envelope.Payload))
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream(envelope.Payload.Length))
            {
                var sha512 = YellowAesEncryptor.DecryptStream(inputStream, outputStream, encryptionKey, macInitialVector, 0);
                File.WriteAllBytes(destination, outputStream.ToArray());

                _logger.LogStatement($"Finished writing [{envelope.Payload.Length} bytes] to [{destination}].", LogLevel.Debug);
            }
        }
```

`FileStream` implementation:

```
private static void WriteMessageContents(FileServiceResponseEnvelope envelope, string destination, byte[] encryptionKey, byte[] macInitialVector)
        {
            using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(envelope.Payload))
            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream(envelope.Payload.Length))
            {
                var sha512 = YellowAesEncryptor.DecryptStream(inputStream, outputStream, encryptionKey, macInitialVector, 0);
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    var bytes = outputStream.ToArray();
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, envelope.Payload.Length);
                    _logger.LogStatement($"File byte content: [{string.Join(", ", bytes.Take(16))}]", LogLevel.Trace);
                    fs.Flush();
                }

                _logger.LogStatement($"Finished writing [{envelope.Payload.Length} bytes] to [{destination}].", LogLevel.Debug);
            }
        }
```

This method is called from a for loop which first receives the messages I described earlier and then feeds their payloads to the above method:

```
using (var requestSocket = new RequestSocket(fileServiceEndpoint))
            {
                // Envelopes is constructed beforehand
                foreach (var envelope in envelopes)
                {
                    var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    requestSocket.SendMoreFrame(messageTypeBytes);
                    requestSocket.SendMoreFrame(SerializationHelper.SerializeObjectToBuffer(envelope));
                    if (!requestSocket.TrySendFrame(_timeout, signedPayloadBytes, signedPayloadBytes.Length))
                    {
                        var message = $"Timeout exceeded while processing [{envelope.ActionType}] request.";
                        _logger.LogStatement(message, LogLevel.Error);
                        throw new Exception(message);
                    }

                    var responseReceived = requestSocket.TryReceiveFrameBytes(_timeout, out byte[] responseBytes);

                    ...

                    var responseEnvelope = SerializationHelper.DeserializeObject<FileServiceResponseEnvelope>(responseBytes);

                    ...

                    _logger.LogStatement($"Received response with payload of [{responseEnvelope.Payload.Length} bytes].", LogLevel.Info);
                    var destDir = downloadDetails.GetDestinationPath(responseEnvelope.FileId);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(destDir))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir);

                    var dest = Path.Combine(destDir, idsToFileNames[responseEnvelope.FileId]);

                    WriteMessageContents(responseEnvelope, dest, encryptionKey, macInitialVector);
                }
            }
```

I also know that TIFs have a very specific header, which looks something like this in raw bytes:

`[73, 73, 42, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 20, 0...`

It always begins with "II" (73, 73) or "MM" (77, 77) followed by 42 (probably a Hitchhiker's reference). I analyzed the bytes written by the utility. The last file always has a header that resembles this one. The rest are always random bytes; seemingly jumbled or mis-ordered image binary data. Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated because I can't wrap my mind around what I would even need to do to diagnose this.

**UPDATE**

I was able to figure out this problem with the help of `elgonzo` in the comments. Sometimes it isn't a direct answer that helps, but someone picking your brain until you look in the right place.

Comment: You have to debug thoroughly. Do not just assume the server sends intact data. **Verify** it. Dump the response data directly into some files and look at them. Try to decrypt the dumped data independently (using another simple program just implementing decryption of those files, so you aren't affected by possible other side effects your actual program might be suffering from). If those dumped files are not decrypted properly, it is either the decryption routine/library or the server itself at fault. If decryption succeed, you will know that there is somehing else going in your program...

Comment: As I explained in my post, the data comes through totally intact if I use only a single argument for an ID, regardless of the file. The only thing that is changing is the number of arguments I provide at once.

Comment: What if the server doesn't like processing multiple requests and sending multiple files back in short order? I am of course not saying that the server is at fault here -- i don't know. But i am also not ruling out the server being the culprit...

Comment: That's possible. I inherited this implementation and, to put it shortly, I wouldn't have necessarily chosen the message queuing library that my predecessor did. I'll take a look at the data as soon as it comes back through the socket instead of waiting for it to be written to the stream.

Comment: Rereading your description again, considering you mentioned only the last file is being intact, i guess it is rather unlikely that the server is at issue here (i would believe a server having trouble with multiple sequential requests would do the first request(s) fine and screw up subsequent requests, not the other way round). Hmm, the code in your question doesn't reveal anything obvious, unfortunately... :-(

Comment: I'm not seeing anything awry with the messages themselves. Of course, the binary data is encrypted before it is passed to the `YellowAesEncryptor.DecryptStream` method above, but that function hasn't caused issues in the past (but unfortunately it's another one that was written before I had a hand in this codebase). However, logically, that's the only thing left for me to look at, since the binary data is coming out of that function corrupted and our messaging service isn't telling me anything else. This might be a larger or different issue beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

All right, as I suspected this was a dumb mistake (I had severe doubts that the File API was simply this flawed for so long). I just needed help thinking through it. There was an additional bit of code which I didn't post that was biting me, when I was retrieving the metadata for the file so that I could then request the file from our storage box.

```
byte[] encryptionKey = null;
byte[] macInitialVector = null;
...
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(uploadedFileQuery, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    FileServiceMessageEnvelope readAllEnvelope = null;
                    var originalFileName = reader["UploadedFileClientName"].ToString();
                    var fileId = Convert.ToInt64(reader["UploadedFileId"].ToString());

                    //var originalFileExtension = originalFileName.Substring(originalFileName.IndexOf('.'));
                    //_logger.LogStatement($"Scooped extension: {originalFileExtension}", LogLevel.Trace);
                    envelopes.Add(readAllEnvelope = new FileServiceMessageEnvelope
                    {
                        ActionType = FileServiceActionTypeEnum.ReadAll,
                        FileType = FileTypeEnum.UploadedFile,
                        FileName = reader["UploadedFileServerName"].ToString(),
                        FileId = fileId,
                        WorkerAuthorization = null,
                        BinaryTimestamp = DateTime.Now.ToBinary(),
                        Position = 0,
                        Count = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UploadedFileSize"]),
                        SignerFqdn = _messengerConfig.FullyQualifiedDomainName
                    });

                    readAllEnvelope.SignMessage(_messengerConfig.PrivateKeyBytes, _messengerConfig.PrivateKeyPassword);
                    signedPayload = new SecureMessage { Payload = new byte[0] };
                    signedPayload.SignMessage(_messengerConfig.PrivateKeyBytes, _messengerConfig.PrivateKeyPassword);
                    signedPayloadBytes = SerializationHelper.SerializeObjectToBuffer(signedPayload);
                    encryptionKey = (byte[])reader["UploadedFileEncryptionKey"];
                    macInitialVector = (byte[])reader["UploadedFileEncryptionMacInitialVector"];
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
```

Eagle-eyed observers might realize that I have not properly coupled the `encryptionKey` and `macInitialVector` to the correct record, since each file has a unique key and vector. This means I was using the key for **one** of the files to decrypt **all of them** which is why they were all corrupt except for one file -- they were not properly decrypted. I solved this issue by coupling them together with the ID in a simple POCO and retrieving the appropriate key and vector for each file upon decryption.